# Battery problem for paddy harvester

Tags: ac, alternator, battery-drain

My harvester vehicle is Claas make. Model Crop tiger 40. I locally fabricated AC cabin for this vehicle. After AC installation, if my vehicle run one day in AC next day morning it is not getting self started. I have to make it started with double battery. Previously I was using 64 Amp alternator. After this problem I changed my alternator to 100 Amps. But now also problem is not solving. Is there  any need to increase my battery capacity? Please suggest

Comment: Did you install a mechanical or electrical AC unit on your harvester?

Comment: It is electrical compressor unit

Comment: It is electrical

Comment: I would suggest there is a power drain due to the AC. You need to figure out where the power drain is coming from and eliminate it. Adding more batteries or even a larger alternator is not going to help the situation.